# How to Parse JIRA Feed XML

Tags: xml, parsing, jira

I can get the Feed from JIRA which is in the XML Format.

Some of the Fields are in the Table Format. Is there any way to parse this Table formatted Fields.

This is the xml file which i received as JIRA Feed:

```
    <!--  RSS generated by JIRA (6.2.3#6260-sha1:63ef1d6dac3f4db4c1effd408ccdc558) at Fri Aug 22 11:49:04 IST 2014 -->
    <?xml-stylesheet href="http://localhost:8080/styles/jirarss2html.xsl" type="text/xsl"?><rss version="2.0">    
    <channel>      
    <title>Demo</title>        
    <link>http://localhost:8080/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&amp;jqlQuery=</link>     
    <description>An XML representation of a search request</description>'#$A'                
    <language>en-us</language>      
    <issue start="0" end="4" total="4"/>     
    <build-info>            
    <version>6.2.3</version>            
    <build-number>6260</build-number>      
    <build-date>15-04-2014</build-date>      
    </build-info>'#$A'
    <item>   
    <title>[W-4] First Issue</title>
    <link>http://localhost:8080/browse/W-4</link>'#$A'    
    <description>
    &lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;'#$A#$A'.tableBorder, .grid'#$A'{'#$A'    background-color: #fff;'#$A'    width: 100%;'#$A'    border-collapse: collapse;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'.tableBorder td, .grid td'#$A'{'#$A'    vertical-align: top;'#$A'    padding: 2px;'#$A'    border: 1px solid #ccc;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'.noPadding'#$A'{'#$A'    padding: 0 !important;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'h3 .subText'#$A'{'#$A'    font-size: 60%;'#$A'    font-weight: normal;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'.tabLabel'#$A'{'#$A'    font-weight: bold;'#$A'    border: 1px solid #ccc;'#$A'    border-bottom:none;'#$A'    padding: 2px;'#$A'    display: inline;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'td.blank'#$A'{'#$A'    padding: 0;'#$A'    margin: 0;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'.blank td'#$A'{'#$A'    border: none;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'#descriptionArea'#$A'{'#$A'    margin: 0;'#$A'    padding: 2px;'#$A'    border: 1px solid #ccc;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'hr'#$A'{'#$A'    border-top:1px solid #aaa;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'hr.fullcontent'#$A'{'#$A'  height: 15px;'#$A'  padding: 10px 0;'#$A'  background: #fff url(&apos;http://localhost:8080/images/icons/hr.gif&apos;) no-repeat scroll center;'#$A'}'#$A#$A'&lt;/style&gt;'#$A' '#$A'&lt;table class=&quot;tableBorder&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;'#$A'&lt;/style&gt
<table class="tableBorder" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">'#$A'    <tr>'#$A'        <td bgcolor="#f0f0f0" width="100%" colspan="2" valign="top">'#$A'                            <h3 class="formtitle">
'#$A'                        [W-4]&nbsp;<a href="http://localhost:8080/browse/W-4">First Issue</a>'#$A'        
    <span class="subText">'#$A'               Created: 22/Aug/14                   &nbsp;Updated: 22/Aug/14'#$A#$A'                                            </span>'#$A'            </h3>'#$A'        </td>'#$A'    </tr>'#$A'   
 <tr>'#$A'       
 <td width="20%"><b>Status:</b></td>'#$A'       
 <td width="80%">To Do</td>'#$A'    </tr>'#$A'    <tr>'#$A'        <td width="20%"><b>Project:</b></td>'#$A'        <td width="80%"><a href="http://192.168.7.167:8080/secure/BrowseProject.jspa?id=10000">WO_Traffic</a></td>'#$A'    </tr>'#$A#$A'      
  <tr>'#$A'            <td><b>Component/s:</b></td>'#$A'            <td>'#$A'                            None'#$A'                </td>'#$A'    </tr>'#$A'    '#$A#$A'        <tr>'#$A'            <td><b>Affects Version/s:</b></td>'#$A'            <td>'#$A'                            None'#$A'                </td>'#$A'   
 </tr>'#$A'    '#$A#$A'        <tr>'#$A'            <td><b>Fix Version/s:</b></td>'#$A'            <td>'#$A'                            None'#$A'                </td>'#$A'    </tr>'#$A'    '#$A'    </table>
    </description>

and so on...
```

In this i can able to get the Fields like 1. Title 2.link.

But After `<Description>` tag everything is like Html Table Format. Is there any way to parse this?

Comment: there are several means to parse an xml file...what technology(programming language) do you normally use ?

Comment: I'd parse the XML and then once you have the contents of the description element, parse that with an HTML parser. Most languages have some library that will do that. It will only have table elements if the HTML has tables in it